# Does Battle Song Expertise work with Moment of Escape?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, feats

The additional effect from the Battle Song Expertise feat reads:

> You also gain a +1 feat bonus to the number of squares that you can
>   pull, push, or slide creatures with your bard **attacks** and bard paragon
>   path attacks.

Moment of Escape allows the bard to slide an ally up to four squares. However, doesn't the fact that it's a utility power and not an attack power technically mean that the feat effect won't work with Moment of Escape?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Correct.**

[Battle Song Expertise](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=3740)'s secondary effect (the one you quoted) kicks in only when you make an attack.

Technically, is not the fact that [Moment of Escape](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=6610) is an Utility power that prevents the usage of that feat: it's the fact that it does not provide an attack (as most Utility powers, by the way).

In fact, the sliding is provided by an **Effect** clause and this clause does not explicitly refer to an attack.

> **Moment of Escape** - **Bard Utility 2**
>   *You distract your enemies with a quick refrain, giving your embattled ally a chance to get away.*
>   **Encounter * Arcane**
>   **Move Action** - **Ranged** 10
>   **Target:** One ally
>   **Effect:** You slide the target 4 squares.